# How can I setup a Linux User with Permission to Upload/download files for 1 specific folder?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

I have an EC2 instance where my backend code and OS is running.

Say it was like this:

**Home Folder**

- AppBackend
- MainLinuxUser
- NewUser

I want NewUser to be able to upload the new AppBackend on the Server but not being able to do anything else - so not even open the Folder: MainLinuxUser.

Is that possible?

Also, I have already shared the entire backend source code with my new developer previously, so does that even matter right now?

Or perhaps, I should also not let him access the current live AppBackend folder too?

*UPDATE*

Would this be an example of Linux User I create that only has permission to read/write:

- $ sudo adduser Max
- $ sudo adduser Max --disabled-password
- (Created a new Key pairs from the EC2 Console)
- $ mkdir .ssh
- $ chmod 700 .ssh. --> this only allows Max to read/write/open his* .ssh but I would also want to have that perm to
  check on whats he doing actually
- $ touch .ssh/authorized_keys
- $ chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys --> like that Max can only read and write his own .ssh folder

**Conclusion**: I am sharing directly the original (private?) key file that has been created in the Amazon EC2 console with Max so that he is able to SSH to my server, using the Keypair I have created for him and upload the new files for my App and configure everything accordingly. Max is not able to view/download any other files on my server.

Is this correct?

Comment: Max can have only access to .ssh folder as you provided and based on your server configuration, he may have access, if anyone provided chomd xx7 to any directory OR Max is assign to any group which have access.

Answer (score 1):

Hope This help you to understand the permissions in Linux:

To change the permissions for a file or folder, use the chmod command.

The **chmod** command lets you specify three numbers which set the permissions: 
Read = 4, Write = 2, Execute = 1.

Add the numbers together for a mixture of permissions. 
For example, to attribute read and execute permissions, the number is 5 (4+1), or for read and write permissions, the number is 6 (4+2).

You must specify three numbers as part of the chmod command. 
The first number is for the owner permissions, the second is for the group permissions, and the last is for everyone else.

For example, for the owner to have full permissions, the group to have read and execute permissions, and anyone else to have no permissions

```
chmod 750 <folder name>
```

In your scenario you can give permissions to all folders as per requirement.
We can go with a group or specific user or by Admin permissions.